# async WhenAll in WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, task, async-await

I'm trying to run a batch of requests in parallel, and wait for those batches to finish. I was thinking of WhenAll in a WhenAll, but when I do this in my main project, the project hangs, the CPU goes to 100% and my RAM starts filling up.

I did a simpler program trying to reproduce the issue, but the issue isn't there. The fact that it is hard to comprehend in my main project using this type of flow, makes me wonder if there is an easier way to model multiple layers of parralelized and sequential requests. I'm looking for best practices for complexe async, thanks.

Here is the simpler program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Test, press key ...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            new TaskParralelizor()
                .Run()
                .Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Test Completed ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class TaskParralelizor
    {
        public async Task Run()
        {
            var parralizedTasks = new List<Task>
                {
                    OneAsync(),
                    TwoAsync()
                };
            await Task.WhenAll(parralizedTasks);
        }

        public Task OneAsync()
        {

            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            tasks.Add(new FakeFetch().FetchAsync("OneAsync() 1", 2500));
            tasks.Add(new FakeFetch().FetchAsync("OneAsync() 2", 4000));
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        public Task TwoAsync()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            tasks.Add(new FakeFetch().FetchAsync("TwoAsync() 1", 2000));
            tasks.Add(new FakeFetch().FetchAsync("TwoAsync() 2", 5000));
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }

    public class FakeFetch
    {
        public Task FetchAsync(string methodName, int time)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Console.WriteLine(methodName + " completed !");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting code that *doesn't* demonstrate the problem doesn't help us much, unfortunately - although it's appreciated that you made the effort at all :) What happens if you break into the debugger in the real app? Are you able to see what tasks are executing? What diagnostics do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @JonSkeet , I understand having the original code would help. The flow/concept are the same, the method type are also, the main difference is this smaller (and works). The original has SOAP requests and linq to sql database calls. It seems like the code goes into a loop. If I debug and look into the call stack, all tasks are waiting for activation. Once I step on the top level whenall await keyword , it hangs. If I step on var t = Task.WhenAll(), it doesn't hang, but await t would.

Comment: My guess is that you've got something recursive going on. I suggest you copy your broken code, and gradually remove bits of it - e.g. replacing SOAP requests with "artificially delayed" hard-coded responses. That way you should be able to gradually reduce it down to something like the code you've posted here - but in a way that still demonstrates the brokenness.

Comment: @JonSkeet There was indeed recursivity (accidental) in my code. When I want to make for exemple MyMethod async, I'll do: Task MyMethodAsync(){ return Task.Run(()=> MyMethod() }. I accidentally wrote MyMethodAsync in the Task.Run. Thanks for the Help Jon. As a side note, is my conversion technique to async considered a good?

Comment: In terms of wrapping synchronous APIs in Task.Run - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx